# Count number of overlapping intervals under memory constraints?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I need to maintain a list of intervals in the form of  tuple (x, y) and answer queries which ask for the total number of intervals overlapping a point p.
If there is no memory constraint i think the efficient solution would be to use a segment tree which requires O(nlogn) space by storing additional information in each node and using lazy update technique.

I tried to do it using an interval tree but the query's runtime depends on the number of reported intervals.

Can we do something better than this under memory constraints?

Comment: Is the list of intervals dynamic ?  Are you concerned with updates and deletions to/from it, or only queries ?  Do you want to know which intervals a point lies in or only the number of intervals it lies in ?  How many intervals are their likely to be ?  Are their endpoints real numbers or integers ?

Comment: @High Performance Mark Yes the list of intervals is dynamic, and updation and deletion takes place along with queries. I want only the number of intervals. The numbers of intervals may be large. The ends points are integers.

Comment: large as in 10^6 or large as in 10^12 ?  Are there any bounds on the end points of the range which includes all the intervals ?

Comment: end points of range are 0 and ~ 10^10

Comment: @High Performance Mark It is large as in 10^6. Hmm, but i want a solution that does not depend on the number of reported intervals.

Answer (score 1):

A better solution is Fenwick Trees (also known as binary index trees), which have the restriction that you can either update a range and query a point or update a point and query a range. Since you update ranges and query a point a Fenwick Tree is a good solution.

They have O(log N) lookup and use O(N) space, where N is the range of x and y. Additionally updates are O(log N) too.

Best of all is they are trivial to code. Much more trivial than Segment Trees.

Here is a great tutorial: [TopCoder - Binary Index Trees](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binaryIndexedTrees)